# Printing the Processing File followed by the <id>

Tags: c#, string

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = textBox1.Text;
    string[] lines = value.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()); 
    foreach (string l in lines)
    if (l.IndexOf("Processing")==0)
    {
       textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + l + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(value, "\"([^\"]*)\"");
    foreach (Match match2 in matches2)
    {
        foreach (Capture capture2 in match2.Captures)
        {              
            textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine + capture2.Value;   

        }
    }
}
```

**MY Input is:-**

```
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt

<"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs">

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt

<"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs">

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt
```

**I Need Output :-**

```
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt

"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs"

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt

"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs"

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt
```

**I Am getting :-**

```
Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt


Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt


Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\New.txt

Processing \\Users\\bhargava\\Desktop\\New.txt

"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs"

"dfgsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfsgfs"
```

Please help me out!

Comment: You're performing your matches against a variable called `value`.  What is that and where do you set its value?

Comment: @ Adrian   string value = textBox1.Text;

Comment: i just need to know how to print the values(like what i have written above in the I need output)

Comment: And I'm trying to help you with that, but first I need to understand why your code is producing the output you're showing us.

Comment: textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + l + Environment.NewLine;  and textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine + capture2.Value **both are being printed in the same textbox so, i will get that only.**that is not what i am intrested ..Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming from the previous version of this question that you deleted that you have your code wrapped in a loop over each of the lines in `textBox1`.  With this in mind I put together a simple program to replicate your code and try to find out what is happening, and I get completely different output to you.  Could you please post the entire class of the form so we can see what might be going on there?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ string value = textBox1.Text;            
string[] lines = value.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());    
foreach (string l in lines)
if (l.IndexOf("Processing")==0)
{
 textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + l + Environment.NewLine;
}
MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(value, "\"([^\"]*)\"");
foreach (Match match2 in matches2)
{
foreach (Capture capture2 in match2.Captures)
{              
textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine +capture2.Value;         
}
}
}This is the code in the button click i have 4 textboxes.Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but please edit your post to put the code in there.

Comment: @Adrian I did change the code.It is all i got.?Help me out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a missing pair of curly braces in your code.  The first foreach needs curly braces to encapsulate all the code that comes afterwards.  Without it it just grabs the next statement and repeats it for each of the elements of lines.  That's why you're getting each of the lines that starts with "Processing" followed by the two matches of your ID.  Try this instead:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string[] lines = value.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()); 
        foreach (string l in lines)
        {
            if (l.IndexOf("Processing")==0)
            {
               textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + l + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(l, "\"([^\"]*)\"");
            foreach (Match match2 in matches2)
            {
                foreach (Capture capture2 in match2.Captures)
                {              
                    textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + Environment.NewLine + capture2.Value;   

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So in this example I added the curly braces I mentioned, and I also got rid of `value` and instead told the regex to search the current line.  If you search value each time you'll end up with way more repetitions of the ID than your desired output says you're looking for.